# How to connect to particular database in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

Suppose I have multiple Oracle databases in the same server. Now I want to connect to particular database and query a table just like SQL Server 2008. How to start particular Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL*Plus, the most common syntax for opening a connection is

```
sqlplus user_name/password@tns_alias
```

In this example `TNS_ALIAS` is the TNS alias for the particular database you want to connect to (most likely "XE" based on your followups to inium's answer).  If you want to connect to a different database, you would need to specify a TNS alias for that specific database.

Note that since you are coming from a SQL Server background, the SQL Server definition of a database is rather different than the Oracle definition.  What SQL Server calls a database is similar logically to what Oracle calls a schema (and similar physically to what Oracle calls a tablespace).  So when you're dealing with Oracle, it's much more common to have many schemas in a single database than to have a large number of databases on a server.  This is particularly true if you're using the Express Edition (Oracle XE) where you're generally limited to one database per machine.

Comment: where can i find good Oracle and Sql Server databases comparison and tutorials. Yes i am switching from Sql Server to Oracle. I want to understand Oracle Concepts as compared to Sql Server.

Comment: @Mohan - All of Oracle's documentation is online at http://tahiti.oracle.com.  The Concepts guide is a great place to start.  That explains how Oracle is architected and should help you understand where Oracle differs from what you understand about SQL Server and where it is similar.  I haven't found many sites that do a particularly good job of comparing and contrasting feature by feature-- they either end up far too high-level to be terribly beneficial or have to repeatedly re-explain the same architectural differences.

Answer (score 2):

go to cmd and type `sqlplus <database-name>/<database-password>`

Comment: What error are you getting ?
Does your sqlplus start when you enter it on cmd ?

Comment: I am getting this error "invalid username or password" i have used following command sql>connect XE/password WHERE XE IS MY DATABASE NAME.

Comment: Then I think you should check your username and password because the way I described above is the right way to connect to a database

Comment: XE looks like an Oracle instance name. What is the username that you are using to connect to your database?

Comment: @Olaf: USER NAME IS SYSTEM. yes xe is database name.

Comment: when you install the database for the first time you can most probably connect to it by typing `sqlplus system/system` and then when you have created new db use their Username password

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), it's similar to SQL Enterprise Manager 2005. Just create a new connection using the db user name and password.

Comment: It will be tough enough to work on cmd based databases for the sql developers. Which Gui tool can i use for Oracle??

Comment: I also switched from MS SQL Server to Oracle and using SQL Developer let everything easier. It's a java base graphical tool for Oracle. Just acess the link above, there you'll find all necessary documentation, tutorials and downloads.